# Using AWS Secrets Manager to hide API keys

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, react-native, aws-secrets-manager

I want to publish an app which is ready but the API keys for AWS Rekognition are hard coded, so I learned I would have to use a lambda function to trigger the rekognition. I did that but I still need the API keys to trigger the lambda function, which I wasn't expecting, so I learned I would have to use Secret Manager. So I created that, the only problem is that I'm still needing to set the API keys to get the secret, so I'm back to square one.

In react native documentation says you can use these services to hide API keys, but after doing all of that I'm still in the same situation. Am I doing something wrong? How do I hide my API key and secret key?

This code is telling me missing credentials:

> LOG  Error fetching IDJson: [CredentialsError: Missing credentials in
> config, if using AWS_CONFIG_FILE, set AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG=1]

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { SecretsManager, config } from 'aws-sdk';


export const useIDJson = () => {
    const [IDJson, setIDJson] = useState(null);
    const [isIDReady, setIsIDReady] = useState(false);
    
    config.update({ region: 'us-east-2' });
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchIDJson = async () => {
      try {
        const secretName = 'faceCompareApp';  
        const secretsManager = new SecretsManager();
        const secretData = await secretsManager.getSecretValue({ SecretId: secretName }).promise();
        const IDJson = JSON.parse(secretData.SecretString);
        setIDJson(IDJson);
        setIsIDReady(true);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log('Error fetching IDJson:', error);
      }
    };

    fetchIDJson();
  }, []);

  return { IDJson, isIDReady };
};
```

Comment: Typically you'd deploy a server or web service (e.g. EC2 or AWS Lambda and API Gateway) that your users would authenticate to and that would make AWS API requests on behalf of authenticated users. Or use Cognito to authenticate your users because Cognito can deliver temporary, limited-privilege AWS credentials to your client application (see [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/getting-credentials.html)) and then the client application can make AWS API requests directly.